# set related childs in ef core to Entity State unchanged

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF Core 5 and use for adding a new entity the Add Method. In the change tracker I saw that the entity state was set to added which is correct.

My Problem is now, if I want to add a new Entity and this new entity has already relations to other entities, this added Entity state is also set for the child entities, but they are already exist.

So is there an easy way to set all child entities with one method to the Entity State Unchanged or Modified?